# Azure Functions: configure blob trigger only for new events

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have about 800k blobs in my azure storage. When I create azure function with a blobTrigger it starts to process all blobs that I have in the storage. How can I configure my function to be triggered only for new and updated blobs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently. Internally we track which blobs we have processed by storing receipts in our control container `azure-webjobs-hosts`. Any blob not having a receipt, or an old receipt (based on blob ETag) will be processed (or reprocessed). That's why your existing blobs are being processed - they don't have receipts. `BlobTrigger` is currently designed to ensure that ALL blobs in a container matching the path pattern are eventually processed, and reprocessed any time they are updated.

If you feel passionately about this, you can log a feature request in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues) with details on your scenario.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I will file a feature request. But for now is there any workaround? Can I generate all receipts on my own?

Comment: No real workaround, short of letting all the blobs be processed. You could write a noop function and let it churn through all the blobs, which would generate the receipts. Once that is done, put your actual function logic in place and going forward those old blobs would only be reprocessed if changed.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about this too, but I'm a bit afraid that it will take too long. Anyway I will try. Thanks for the help

Comment: FYI, there's a new issue tracking this here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1327

Comment: @mathewc writing a noop function is a great idea, but what about if I ran this then I wanted to reprocess processed blobs one again, should I just clear the `azure-webjobs-hosts`?

Answer (score 3):

I know that question is so old, but my answer can help a new dev to fix it.

On BlobTrigger you can use parameter `BlobProperties`, that it has the properity `Created` and filter this date.

```
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("xyz/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream file, string name, ILogger logger, BlobProperties Properties)
{
    if(Properties.Created < new DateTime(2022, 03, 18, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("SKIP");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I get around this is to set Metadata on a processed Blob (e.g Status = Complete).  When the trigger gets fired I first check for this piece of Metadata and return the function if it is already set.

The downside to this is that the update of the Metadata will trigger an additional execution of the function

Comment: Also thought of this - but doesn't that require fetching every blob as an InputStream into the Function before adjudicating on its metadata? I don't know whether the fetching of the blob is deferred until the (in python) read(). For 800k images is that feasible?